# Why to Export Component from One Module & Use in Another Module Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-module

I have been trying to work on this for long hours. However, I'm finally giving up and looking for community support on this. Thanks in advance for the help!

I have Web Projects Module which uses Webpage Component. I am importing Objects Module (which has a Navbar Component & ComponentLoaderDirective) in the Webprojects Module.

& I am trying to Load the Contents of navbar.html to webpage.component.html

Why does Angular force me to import NavbarComponent & ComponentLoaderDirective again in weboage.components.ts? Without the same I get below errors:
Cannot find the name 'Navbar Component'.
Cannot find the name 'ComponentLoaderDirective'.

I think I'm missing something here. Just not able to locate what is missing.

webprojects.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Global } from '../../../class.global'; //Global Class Contains the Global Variables & Functions Being Used Throughout the Project.
import { StartupService } from 'src/app/services/shared/startup.service'; //StartupService is Used to Get the Project, Page, Object & Elements on Page Load.
import { ObjectsModule } from './objects/objects.module';
import { WebpageComponent } from './webpage/webpage.component'; //WebProjectsModule Uses WebpageComponent as the View (webpage.component.html) & Controller (webpage.component.html).

@NgModule({
  declarations: [WebpageComponent], //WebProject Module Uses the Webpage Component
  imports: [HttpClientModule, ObjectsModule],
  exports: [], //Webprojects Module Exports the Webpage Component to the App Module & Other Modules Using the WebProjects Module
  providers: [StartupService, Global] //StartupService, GlobalClass are Required for the WebProjects Module to Work.  
})
export class WebProjectsModule {}
```

webpage.component.ts

```
//Webpage Component is the First Component to be loaded Under the Webprojects Module.
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Global } from '../../../../class.global'; //Global Class Contains the Global Variables & Functions Being Used Throughout the Project.
import { Error } from '../../../../services/shared/error' //Error Class is Used to Display Errors
import { StartupService } from '../../../../services/shared/startup.service'; //StartupService is Required to Load the Project, Page, Object & Elements.
import { Project } from '../../../../services/projects/webprojects/project'; //Project Model is Required to Constrain the Type of Data Being Received from the Startup Service getProjects().
import { Projectpage } from '../../../../services/projects/webprojects/projectpage'; //Project Page Model is Required to Constrain the Type of Data Being Received from the Startup Service getProjectPage().
import { Pageobject } from '../../../../services/projects/webprojects/pageobject'; //Page Object Model is Required to Constrain the Type of Data Being Received from the Statup Service getPageObjects().
import { Property } from '../../../../services/projects/webprojects/property'; //Property Object Model is Required to Constrain the Type of Property Array Being Created for Objects & Elements.
import { SEOService } from '../../../../services/shared/seo.service'; //SEO Service is Used to Display the Page Title, Description, Other SEO Related Content on the Page.
import { ComponentLoaderDirective } from '../../../../services/shared/component-loader.directive';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../objects/navbar/navbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-webpage',
  templateUrl: './webpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./webpage.component.scss']
})
export class WebpageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(ComponentLoaderDirective, {static: true}) pageObjectLoader!: ComponentLoaderDirective;

  responseProject: Project[] = []; //Variable of Type Project Array Used to Store the Array of Projects Received from the Startup Service getProjects().
  project: any = {}; //Variable of Type Any Used to Store the Parameters of the Current Project being Loaded. Initializing with Empty Object.
  projectId: number = 0; //Variable of Type Number Used to Store the Id of the Current Project being Loaded. Initilizing with 0.
  projectType: string = 'web'; //Variable of Type String Used to Store the Type of the Current Project being Loaded. Initializing with web.
  responseProjectPage: Projectpage[] = []; //Variable of Type Projectpage Array Used to Store the Object of Projectpage Received from the Statup Service getProjectPage().
  projectPage: any = {}; //Aggregate of Type Object Used to Store the Parameters of Project Page, Project & Page. Initializing with Empty Object.
  projectPageProperties: Property[] = []; //Variable of Type Property[] Used to Store Array of Properties of Project Page.
  page: any = {}; //Variable of Type Any Used to Store the Parameters of the Current Page being Loaded.
  pageTitle: string = ''; //Variable of Type String Used to Store the Title of the Current Page being Loaded.
  pageDescription: string = ''; //Variable of Type String Used to Store the Description of the Current Page being Loaded.
  pageProperties: Property[] = []; //Variable of Type Property Used to Store the Properties of the Page being Loaded.
  pageType: string = 'home'; //Variable of Type String Used to Store the Type of Current Page being Loaded. Initializing with home by default to be loaded. Unless Overwritten by the Route.
  pageObjects: Pageobject[] = []; //Variable of Type Any Used to Store the Page & Object Parameters Relevant to the Page Being Loaded. Initializing with Empty Object.
  pageObjectProperties: Property[] = []; //Variable of Type Property[] Used to Store the Array of Page Object Properties.
  object: any = {}; //Variable of Type Any Used to Store the Object Relevant to the Page Being Loaded. Initializing with Empty Object.
  objectProperties: Property[] = []; //Variable of Type Property[] Used to Store the Array of Object Properties.
  properties: Property[] = []; //Variable of Type Property[] Used to Store Array of Properties.
  active: boolean = true; //Initializing with true. All the Requests to Get the Projects, ProjectPages & PageObjects are with Active = true.
  global = new Global();
  error = new Error();

  constructor(private startupService: StartupService, private seoService: SEOService) {};

  async ngOnInit(){
    try{
      this.responseProject = await this.startupService.getProjects(this.projectType,this.active).toPromise();  
      var i = this.responseProject.length;
      while(i--){
        if(this.responseProject[i].tags.indexOf(window.location.href) == -1){ //Using window.location.href to Get the Url Which Was Loaded & Get the Project Accordingly.
          this.responseProject.splice(i, 1); //Removes the Project from the Array if it is Not Relevant to the Current Project.
        }
      };

      if(this.responseProject.length > 0){ //Checks if Atleast 1 Project is Received.
        this.project = this.responseProject[0]; //Storing the Relevant Project in the Project Variable
        this.projectId = this.project.nid; //Storing the Relevant Project Id in the projectId Variable.

        this.responseProjectPage = await this.startupService.getProjectPage(this.projectId, this.pageType, this.active).toPromise();
        //Use the getPage() in StartupService to Get the Home Page of the Relevant Project Being Loaded.
        if(Object.keys(this.responseProjectPage).length === 1){ //Checks if the Array Received is Not Empty.          
          this.projectPage = this.responseProjectPage[0]; //Aggregate Object Received from the Database is Stored in projectPage Variable.
          this.projectPageProperties = this.projectPage.properties; //Project Page Properties which are a Part of the Aggregate Received is Separately Stored in projectPageProperties Variable.

          this.page = this.projectPage.page; //Page Object which is Part of the Aggregate Received is Separately Stored in page Variable.
          this.pageProperties = this.page.properties; //Page Properties which are a Part of the Page Object Received are Separately Stored in pageProperties Variable.
          
          //We Pick All the Properties from projectPageProperties & the Remaining Properties from pageProperties which are Not a Part of projectPageProperties.
          var namesToFilter = new Set(this.projectPageProperties.map(d => d.name)); //We Get All the Names in the projectPageProperties Array and Store them in namesToFilter Array.
          this.properties = [...this.projectPageProperties, ...this.pageProperties.filter(d => !namesToFilter.has(d.name))]; //We Merge Both the Arrays and Skip the Objects with Names in the namesToFilter Array.
          
          //Looping through the Properties Array to Get the Page Title & Description for the <head> Tag.
          this.properties.forEach((property: Property) => {   
            this.pageTitle = (property.name === 'pgTitle')?property.value:this.pageTitle;      
            this.pageDescription = (property.name === 'pgDescription')?property.value:this.pageDescription;
          });                
          this.seoService.updateTitle(this.pageTitle); //Using the SEO Service, We Update the <html><head><title> Tag of the Page.
          this.seoService.updateDescription(this.pageDescription); //Using the SEO SErvice, We Update the <html><head><meta = "description"> Tag is the Page.

          this.pageObjects = this.projectPage.pageobjects; //Storing the Page Objects Array in pageObjects Variable.
          if(this.pageObjects.length > 0){ //Checking if there is Atleast One Page Object.
            const viewContainerRef = this.pageObjectLoader.viewContainerRef; //We Use Instance of Component Loader Directive to Define Where to Load the Child Component.

            this.pageObjects.forEach((pageObject: Pageobject) => { //Looping through the Page Objects.
              this.pageObjectProperties = pageObject.properties; //Storing the Page Object Properties Array in pageObjectProperties Variable.              

              this.object = pageObject.object; //Storing the Object which is Part of Page Object in the object Variable.
              this.objectProperties = this.object.properties; //Storing the Properties of Object in the objectProperties Variable.

              //We Pick All the Properties from pageObjectProperties & the Remaining Properties from objectProperties which are Not a Part of pageObjectProperties.
              namesToFilter = new Set(this.pageObjectProperties.map(d => d.name)); //We Get All the Names in the pageObjectProperties Array and Store them in namesToFilter Array.
              this.properties = [...this.pageObjectProperties, ...this.objectProperties.filter(d => !namesToFilter.has(d.name))]; //We Merge Both the Arrays and Skip the Objects with Names in the namesToFilter Array.

              switch(this.object.path){ //Based on the Path of Object We Load the Respective Component.
                case 'NavbarComponent':{ //NavbarComponent Relates with the Object Type of navbar.
                  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<any>(NavbarComponent);
                  componentRef.instance.properties = this.properties;
                  break;
                }
              };
            });
          } else { //Throw Error if No Page Objects Were Received.
            this.error.display('Error Loading Project in webpage.component. Unable to Fetch Page Objects Data...');
          };          
        } else { //Throw Error if Query Ran Succcessfully. However, No Project Page Was Received.
          this.error.display('Error Loading Project in webpage.component. Unable to Fetch Project Page Data...');
        };
      } else { //Throw Error if Query Ran Succcessfully. However, No Projects Were Received.
        this.error.display('Error Loading Project in webpage.component. Unable to Fetch Projects Data...');    
      };
    } catch(error){
      this.error.display('Error Loading Project in webpage.component...', error);
    };
  };
};
```

webpage.component.html

```
<ng-template pageObjectLoader></ng-template>
<div>Webpage Works!</div>
```

objects.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ComponentLoaderDirective } from '../../../../services/shared/component-loader.directive';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';

let components = [NavbarComponent, ComponentLoaderDirective];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [components],
  imports: [CommonModule, MaterialModule],
  exports: [components]
})
export class ObjectsModule {}
```

navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Property } from '../../../../../services/projects/webprojects/property';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() properties: Property[] = []; //Properties of Navbar Component
  @Input() elements: any; //Elements of Navbar Component

  class: string = '';    
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.properties.forEach((property) => {
      this.class += (property.type = 'class')?(this.class == '')?property.value:' ' + property.value:'';
    });
  };
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar [ngClass]="class">
    <span>Yellow Pages & Classifieds | ypandc.com</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Please remove all the comments in the code, it makes it unnecessarily difficult to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [ngmodule-vs-jsmodule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule) article that explains the difference between jsModules and ngModules. They are 2 different things:

JavaScript modules and NgModules can help you modularize your code, but they are very different. Angular applications rely on both kinds of modules.

1. [ngModule](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules) has an 'import' property that enable importing other modules whose exported classes are needed by component templates declared in this NgModule.
2. [jsModule](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) syntaxt that should be declared in order to use a js module in another .ts file.

The export/import ngModule properties are necessary in order to declare which classes can be imported in other modules, and the second 'import' in your component.ts is just a typescript syntaxt for access an object in your file.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not get the answer. When I import objects.module.ts in webprojects.module.ts. I should be able to use navbar.component.ts (which is part of declarations and exports of objects.module.ts) in the webprojects.module.ts without the import line import { NavbarComponent } from '../objects/navbar/navbar.component';. If I still have to import NavbarComponent in webpage.component.ts then why I need to import objects.module in webprojects.module...

Comment: Please read [ngmodule-vs-jsmodule](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule) article   that explains the difference between js modules and ngModules. Thery are 2 different things.

Comment: @NaveedNaik Please change the title of your question to somtething like  "Why import..." and not "How to export/import..".  you impleneted the code correcly. the question is about  a difference between the 2 modules types.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty simple, don't worry. You need to use a [SCAM](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/emulating-tree-shakable-components-using-single-component-angular-modules-13do) (Single Component Angular Module). An example for you is below:

**Create your module, only export one component! - this is very important**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModuleAComponent],
  exports: [ModuleAComponent],
  imports: [
    ButtonModule // etc
  ],
})
export class ModuleA {}
```

**Import ModuleA in an ModuleB - see, it's simple**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ModuleBComponent],
  exports: [ModuleBComponent],
  imports: [
    ModuleB
  ],
})
export class ModuleB {}
```